# Can the search box be altered to include faq items?

Tags: feature-request

Here from [Where do I look for basic information on logged-in user abilities?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/where-do-i-look-for-basic-information-on-logged-in-user-abilities)

I was quite confused when I was unable to use the search tool to find out more about privileges. I did eventually figure out that I could look in the FAQ, expand the part about "What Is Reputation", and them click on privileges.

I think it would be very helpful, to new users and regulars alike, if the search box allowed one to find things beyond questions on the site.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you include it? You'd otherwise get noise in your searches if you wanted something not related to the FAQ

Comment: In a similar vein, I had troubles searching for a question that said 'search' as it turned it into the tag [search].

Comment: @random: Have the different areas of results separated out? For example, questions, faq, other, and the top 5 results of each shown with an expand arrow if there are more results in that category?

Answer (score 1):

> I was quite confused when I was unable to use the search tool to find out more about privileges. I did eventually figure out that I could look in the FAQ, expand the part about "What Is Reputation", and them click on privileges.

I think this is the part we could improve. How can we make it easier to find the /faq and navigate it (and do bear in mind we *just* rolled out an improved faq layout.)

Answer (score 1):

It could be helpful to include a search prompt on the FAQ page titled:

> I have another question

Right under this section you would have a search field.

Whatever terms they enter, silently include the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag to restrict to those posts. That should bring up a finer, more targeted result.

It might be jarring though to search on Gardening and see another site title appear when you click through.

So maybe caching and pushing out the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) for the other sites in the network for a localised search experience could alleviate this bait and switch feeling.

Comment: This would certainly help, although I don't entirely understand the problem with having different types of searches using the same search box. Having multiple possible search boxes will be confusing, I think!